# “Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8” error for IDEA IntelliJ while compiling java files

Tags: intellij-idea

I am encountering the following error while building a java application in IDEA IntelliJ.

“Unmappable character for encoding UTF-8”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IDEA IntelliJ
Go to File --> Settings --> Editor --> File Encodings

Select UTF-8 for Global and Project Encoding, solved my problem.

[image]